# Backbone.Collection.Create

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to dynamically put option tag in a select list.

When **ADD** button is pressed, the value in the input text is set as a field of a new model, then this model is pushed in the collection (by .create method), and an event is fired to refresh the  select view. The problem is that i need the ID property of newly created model to put it in **DOM** ( a model instance is returned by Collection.create, but fired event passes 'incomplete' model  ).

//OPTION VIEW

```
optionView = Backbone.View.extend({

tagName: 'option',

attributes: function(){
    var f1 = this.model.get("f1");
    var id = this.model.get("id");
    return {
        value: f1,
        id: id
    };
},

render: function(){
    this.$el.text(this.model.get("f1"));
    return this; 
}

});
```

//SELECT VIEW

```
selectView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#container',

collection: selectList,

events: {
    "click #add-season":  "create",
},

initialize: function () {
  var options = this.collection;

    this.$addInput = this.$('#new-opt');  

_.bindAll(this, 'appendOne', 'appendAll');

    options.on('add',     this.appendOne); 
    options.on('reset',   this.appendAll);

    options.fetch(); // Loads list from local storage
},

appendOne: function(opt) { //PROBLEM! opt doesn't have auto-generated ID yet

var view = new app.OptionView({model: opt});

    this.$("#select-list").append( view.render().el );
},

appendAll: function() {
this.$("#select-list").html('');
    this.collection.each(this.appendOne);
},


create: function() { 

    this.collection.create({
        f1: this.$addInput.val() 
    });

    this.$addInput.val('');
}

});
```

Comment: where u generate new ID?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `{wait: true}` if you'd like to wait for the server before adding the new model to the collection.
[create](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)

try, this

```
create: function() { 

    this.collection.create({
        f1: this.$addInput.val() 
    }, {wait : true});

    this.$addInput.val('');
}
```